# Docpad Run, errors and warnings

Tags: docpad

Node.js and Docpad are installed via: http://docpad.org/docs/install

`npm install -fg docpad@6.21`

docpad run via: http://docpad.org/docs/start

`mkdir my-website
cd my-website
docpad run`

Selected `6.) Hogan` (Skeleteon)

and got this:

```
info: Installed the skeleton succesfully
info: DocPad listening to http://localhost:9778/ on directory c:\Users\DM\My Doc
uments\MDM\Web Projects\Client Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\out
info: LiveReload listening to new socket on channel /docpad-livereload with log
level 1
info: Generating...
warning:
  Rendering the extension "eco" to "html" on "index.html.eco" didn't do anything
.
  Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
warning:
  Rendering the extension "eco" to "html" on "footer.html.eco" didn't do anythin
g.
  Explanation here: http://docpad.org/extension-not-rendering
warning: Something went wrong while rendering: c:\Users\DM\My Documents\MDM\Web
Projects\Client Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\src\layouts\default.html.e
co
warning: Something went wrong while rendering: c:\Users\DM\My Documents\MDM\Web
Projects\Client Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\src\layouts\primary.html.e
co
warning: Something went wrong while rendering: c:\Users\DM\My Documents\MDM\Web
Projects\Client Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\src\documents\index.html.e
co
error: Something went wrong with the action
error: An error occured:
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getFileUrl'
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\DM\Documents\MDM\Web Projects\
Client Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\node_modules\docpad-plugin-eco\node
_modules\eco\lib\compiler.js:19:12))
    at Object.eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\DM\Documents\MDM\Web Projects\
Client Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\node_modules\docpad-plugin-eco\node
_modules\eco\lib\compiler.js:19:12))
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\DM\Documents\MDM\Web Projects\Client
Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\node_modules\docpad-plugin-eco\node_module
s\eco\lib\compiler.js:19:12))
    at Function.eco.render (C:\Users\DM\Documents\MDM\Web Projects\Client Projec
ts\Web-Mart\Development\Website\node_modules\docpad-plugin-eco\node_modules\eco\
lib\index.js:26:25)
    at EcoPlugin.module.exports.EcoPlugin.render (C:\Users\DM\Documents\MDM\Web
Projects\Client Projects\Web-Mart\Development\Website\node_modules\docpad-plugin
-eco\out\eco.plugin.js:23:37)
    at Object.balUtilFlow.fireWithOptionalCallback (c:\Users\DM\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\docpad\node_modules\bal-util\out\lib\flow.js:39:27)
    at BasePlugin.bindEvents (c:\Users\DM\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\docpa
d\out\lib\plugin.js:57:26)
    at Object.balUtilFlow.fireWithOptionalCallback (c:\Users\DM\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\docpad\node_modules\bal-util\out\lib\flow.js:32:27)
    at Object.EventEmitterEnhanced.emitSync (c:\Users\DM\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\docpad\node_modules\bal-util\out\lib\events.js:49:30)
    at Object.balUtilFlow.fireWithOptionalCallback (c:\Users\DM\AppData\Roaming\
npm\node_modules\docpad\node_modules\bal-util\out\lib\flow.js:32:27)
```

I've never gotten past these warnings and errors and it'd be very nice to be able to use docpad so I am grateful for any ideas on how to rid my seeming Docpad curse. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the skeleton is broken, I don't know who's maintaining it. Like I mentioned in IRC, for others that might read/need I'll post here too...

You can use a empty folder and do this from the shell or you can just use the empty template:

```
cd $(mktemp -d) && npm i docpad docpad-plugin-hogan && \
mkdir -p src/{documents,files,layouts} && \
curl https://raw.github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-hogan/master/test/src/documents/hogan.html.hogan \
> src/documents/index.html.hogan && docpad run
```

Should work to demonstrate hogan plugin and docpad itself work fine. 
Personally I always start with a package.json but thats just how I like to do it, define plugins as you need them in there but you can all just do it manually as well... Or use the basic HTML5 boilerplate plugin and then add docpad-plugin-hogan etc.

Or wait until it get fixed if you *must* have that skeleton...